# Error trying to create a Dictionary object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, anonymous-types

I need to create a dictionary object in typescript, something that has the following function:

```js
obj.add(key, value); 
obj.remove(key);
obj.contains(key); // returns true/false
obj.get(key); // returns value
```

This was the model I created to accommodate:

```js
export class Dictionary<T, F> {
    items = {};
    constructor() {
      this.items = {};
    }
    public contains(key: T): boolean {
      return key in this.items;
    }
    public add(key: T, value: F): void {
      this.items[key] = value;
    }
    public get(key: T): F {
      return this.items[key];
    }
    public remove(key: T): boolean {
      if (this.contains(key) ){
        delete this.items[key];
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error: src/app/models/dictionary.model.ts:10:7 - error TS2536: Type 'T' cannot be used to index type '{}'.
    
    10       this.items[key] = value;
```

Has anyone come across this before and can recommend the most appropriate fix?

Thanks in advance for any pointers (examples welcome :-))!

Comment: Keys can be numbers or strings and should be constrained as such.

Comment: From TS 4.4, you can also have `symbol` and string patterns as indexed types. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#symbol-template-signatures

Comment: One solution is to remove the generic argument `T` and replace occurrences of that argument in the methods with `number|string`.

Comment: Why don’t you just use `Map` or `WeakMap`?